# Remove multiple configuration set from app target

Tags: xcode, cocoa, cocoapods

My project on Xcode has multiples targets, these targets are all mapped on my `podfile` file like this:

```rb
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

def common_pods
  #Common libraries
end

target 'App1' do
  common_pods
end

target 'App2' do
  common_pods
end

target 'App3' do
  common_pods
end

#There are more app targets, but it's a example.

target 'UnitTests_App1' do
  common_pods
  pod 'Something'
end

target 'UnitTests_App2' do
  common_pods
  pod 'Something'
end

target 'UnitTests_App3' do
  common_pods
  pod 'Something'
end

#So on...
```

After I run pod install, my project configuration looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of configuration]

This is making a mess in my `Build Settings` page, take a example how the Compilation module looks like:

[image: Compilation module setting]

This is unnecessary, I don't need the settings of the target `App2` on the settings of target `App1`. All the time I add a new app or unit test target this situation gets worse.
Cocoapod is changing automatically when I run `pod install`.

What additional setting on `podfile` should I add to solve this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you need to escalate to something that handle better the versions of the app like fastlane? I used to work in a place where we had the same app, just different endpoints, icons and logos for multiple clients, and with one version of the code, fastlane did all the changes needed.

Comment: We use Fastlane on our project but it will a bit complex because I need to use compilation flags to enable/disable features of some apps. I would prefer to solve it on cocoapods level.

Comment: Im not sure if this will be an option, and on the project that I mentioned, the DevOps guy was able to set flags to do different things, i believe the only way will be with fastlane

Comment: I really don't like the idea of adding the dependency of a third party library just to solve this issue, I would rather remove Cocoapods and fix the project manually. 
Is this behaviour normal for a Cocoapods project?

Comment: Yes I have a project that has 3 targets and I get the same behavior as you do

Comment: Do you think I should open a issue on their repo? I can't see any light on this situation.

Comment: I believe that if is there a possible solution, they are the only one that can help, either helping you configuring your pod or developing something to fix this issue, please let us know what was the solution they provide